# Using 2nd router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to add a second router to my network at home. I have one main router on the first floor and at the attic I got the 2nd router. I can connect them together with a cable. I followed one of the guides from the internet. Basically, I have limited IP range on the main router so it covers IPs from 10 to 200. Then I changed the IP address of the second router to 201 and disabled DHCP. Both routers are connected from/to LAN ports. The problem is that I was hoping that this solution will enhance the range of my main WiFi network but I still can see both separate networks. What can I do to make it a single network? It's terrible to be forced to change network every time I change a floor.

Answer (score 3):

You may need just a simple access point, not a router. In other words: one LAN with two WiFi access points, including the one that's built into the 1st router.

Since you've already spent money on a router: setting it in bridge mode will disable routing etc. and leave just the access point feature on.

Set the network name, security and password the same as the first router's. Devices should switch between the two automatically.

Comment: My router DIR-853 is not supporting bridge mode. What kind of Access point unit are you recommending? My goal is to have a single and same network in the whole house.

Comment: Unfortunately even if I knew anything about what's worth buying as of now, I wouldn't be able to help you because I don't know what your needs are.

Comment: @Furjoza Support for bridge mode is not required because consumer-grade Wi-Fi routers always bridge Wi-Fi and Ethernet (LAN ports). You get a "single network" by setting the same network name and password on both devices & connecting them using Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your DIR-853 does not support bridge mode, so you cannot use it as your second router and achieve your goal of having a single network (LAN) in the whole house. Your options are as follows:

- Check if your "main router on the first floor" supports bridge mode. If it does, you can do a swap: replace that router with your DIR-853, then take the first router and put it in the attic. That would fully achieve your goal.
- Buy a router that actually supports bridge mode. This should honestly be pretty easy, most routers from the main brands like Netgear, Asus, etc all support this. Just look for a router you like, then search `<router name> bridge mode` to confirm that it supports bridge mode. Use that router in place of your DIR-853, and your goal would be achieved.
- If you do not want to buy a new access point, you can do as gronostaj suggests and "Set the network name, security and password the same as the first router." This should result in the *appearance* of only one network, in that you would only see one network when connecting on your devices, and all devices would be able to use the internet. But, you would have issues when trying to communicate between devices within your LAN connected to different routers. This may or may not achieve your goal, as I don't know what your needs are.

Comment: The last option should usually work without problems as long as the DIR-853's LAN ports are used (as opposed to the WAN port) – in pretty much all home wireless routers they're already bridged to Wi-Fi regardless of mode.